# TypeError: attr[0].indexOf is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js

While querying through sequelize:

```
where["tenant_id"] = tenant_id;
    where[datecheck] = {
        $gte: from,
        $lte: to,
        $ne: null
    };
group = [ group_by + '_id' , "stage_type"];
attributes = [[group_by + '_id', 'id'], [group_by + '_name', 'group'], ["stage_type", 'type'], [ sequelize.literal('SUM(`stage_value`)'), 'count']];

Model.findAll({
        attributes: attributes,
        where: where,
        group: group
    });
```

I get this error:

> Data TypeError: attr[0].indexOf is not a function
>
> at attributes.map.attr (
>   sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1244:28)

Comment: Can you share the raw query that is getting executed?

Comment: SELECT `tenant_id` AS `id`, `tenant_name` AS `group`, `stage_type` AS `type`, COUNT(`candidate_id`) AS `count` FROM `funnel_reports` AS `funnel_reports` WHERE `funnel_reports`.`tenant_id` = '10' AND (`funnel_reports`.`stage_date` >= '2018-05-31 18:30:00' AND `funnel_reports`.`stage_date` <= '2019-02-28 18:30:00') GROUP BY `tenant_id`, `stage_type`;

Comment: That query I want to run through sequelize but it is throwing an error. I am using sequelize 4.38.0 version

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is thrown when the id in the query is null.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your contribution. Please turn the part I deleted into a comment here. (you can)